# How to print British Pound Sign £ on Epson TM-T88 receipt printer?

Tags: vb.net, epson

I have tried to print pound sign with static as well as ASCII value, but it shows (?) sign in receipt, so is there any other way to print pound sign in receipt?

Comment: You need to change the code page which the printer is using. It looks like the printer's code page 16 (WPC1252) has the pound sign at position 163. (C.f. the &#163; HTML character entity.) Consult the printer's manuals for how to change the code page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after Googling I found code to print Pound sign (£) in receipt printer. I am posting this solution so which might useful other developers in future.

**For ESC/POS type printer(Related to serial port)**

```
Dim bCOM(0) As Byte
bCOM(0) = &H9C
com1.Write(bCOM, 0, 1) 'where com1 is IO.Ports.SerialPort
```

**For OPOS type printer**

```
EpsonOposPrinter.CharacterSet = 1252
EpsonOposPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, Chr(&H1B) + "|N" + "£12.30" + vbCrLf)
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET can be done as follows - tested and Working!

```
'initially set printer to use codepage 1252 with ESC, t,16
Prnstr = Chr(&H1B) + "t" + Chr(16) _
& "Message to print including UK £" _
& Chr(&H1B)+ "t" + Chr(0)  ' set printer back to default codepage

'IMPORTANT requires matching encoding type for string to byte array 
conversion.

Dim data As [Byte]() = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetBytes(Prnstr)
Port.write (data,0,data.length)
```

[epson](/questions/tagged/epson) [esc](/questions/tagged/esc) [pos](/questions/tagged/pos) [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)